# How to check if a user's password is correct without logging them in with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm programming a timeclock system where a user effectively punches their timeclock by entering their `username` and `password` in a specific computer. A timeclock user will first login. I just need to register that a user showed up by checking if the `username` and `password` they entered is correct. How can I do that in `Devise`?

***I don't want to actually log them in***, only check that they are who they say they are. The timeclock user is the only user logged in at all times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use gem devise. Try

```
User.find(1).valid_password?('password123')  # returns true/false
```

That code in file: devise/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb

Answer (score 1):

### Use Devise Methods

Devise gives you two [built-in methods](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Find-a-user-when-you-have-their-credentials) that let you do exactly this:

```
user = User.find_for_authentication(username: params[:username])
user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```